# Why am i getting " NameError: name 'url_prefix' is not defined" what I try to register a blueprint

Tags: python, flask

very confused here.  I have a large flask app that I am trying to migrate to our production server, and the app factory always crashes due the error in the title.  Here's `app/__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from app.extensions import db, login_manager, mail
from history import history
from app.jinja_filters import currency
from app.projects import projects
from app.reporting import reporting
from app.requests import requests
from app.user import users
import logging


def create_app(config):
    logging.basicConfig(
        filename='/<path-to-app-root>/log/por_rm_log.log',
        level=logging.DEBUG,
        format=f'%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(threadName)s : %(message)s'
    )
    
    app = Flask(__name__)
    
    print(f'config is {config}')
    if config == 'development':
        app.config.from_object('config.DevelopmentConfig')
    elif config == 'testing':
        app.config.from_object('config.TestingConfig')
    elif config == 'production':
        app.config.from_object('config.ProductionConfig')
    
    db.init_app(app)
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    mail.init_app(app)
    
    app.register_blueprint(currency)
    app.register_blueprint(history)
    app.register_blueprint(projects)
    app.register_blueprint(reporting)
    app.register_blueprint(requests)
    app.register_blueprint(users)

    @app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
    def index():
        return render_template('base.html.jinja')

    app.logger.info(f'App restarted ({config})')

    return app
```

Here's the declaration of the `projects` blueprint in `app/projects/views.py`:

```
from distutils.util import strtobool
from flask import Blueprint, jsonify, render_template, request
from .lib import compile_por_counts, get_submarkets
from .models import ProjectOfRecord
from app.extensions import db
from app.requests import ChangeRequestForm

projects = Blueprint('projects', __name__, url_prefix='/projects')

....all my routes for projects...
```

When I try to start the production server, it doesn't work.  Here's the traceback the `wsgi_error_log`:

```
File "<path-to-app-root>/app.wsgi", line 10, in <module>
     from wsgi import app as application
File "<path-to-app-root>/wsgi.py", line 5, in <module>
     app = create_app('production')
File "<path-to-app-root>/__init__.py", line 34, in create_app
     NameError: name 'url_prefix' is not defined
```

I'm stumped here.  The blueprints before `projects` register just fine.  TIA!

EDIT:  Because Aryan Jain asked, here are the contents of `/app/projects/__init__.py`:

```
from .views import projects
from .models import ProjectOfRecord
```

Comment: I would check 2 things - first, if you have an `__init__.py` inside `app/projects/` and second, try changing the import for the projects blueprint to `from app.projects.views import projects`

Comment: Error appears inside the create_app method. Why?

Comment: You seem to have an indenation problem at `app = Flask(__name__)`. Shouldn't that and following lines be indented to be in the function?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  That is just an artifact of my cutting & pasting, unfortunately.  I'll correct it now.  Good catch.

Comment: What is `"<path-to-app-root>/__init__.py", line 34`? Strange that its not in the traceback message.

Comment: No dice,  @Aryan.  I edited my post to include the contents of `app/projects/views.py`, and I tried `from app.projects.views import projects`.  I get the same error message.

Comment: `history` and `currency` are they Blueprints ?

Comment: @cizario yes, they are

Comment: do you have a github/gitlab repo ?

Comment: Not for this; its for my corporate job.

Comment: Please show the actual line of code on line 34 of `__init__.py`

Comment: The actual line is `app.register_blueprint(requests)`.  requests came from `from app.requests import requests`, where it's defined `requests = Blueprint('requests', __name__, url_prefix='/requests')` in `app/requests/views.py`.  `app/requests/__init__.py` has the line:  `from .views import requests `

Comment: Well, thanks everybody for trying to help, but it appears this issue is something of a red herring.  There's something wrong (or at least something I don't understand) about the way our wsgi server works.  'touch'-ing app.wsgi does not force the app to reload; that's why everything I tried yesterday resulted in the same error messages.